# Using Linq to find all records in table that have a specific value in a related table using method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

This Linq query syntax works and returns exactly what I need but I would like to understand the equivalent query using Method syntax.

```
from r in Resources 
        from t in r.Teams
        where t.Id ==1
        select r
```

The **Resource** table and the **Team** tables have a many to many relationship.

What would be the fluent or method syntax be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two from clauses is equivalent of [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) operator. But in this case it will be overload of SelectMany operator which also invokes result selector function on each element:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>> collectionSelector,
    Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector
)
```

it not only flattens sequence of resources, but also produces new sequence which contains both resource and team

```
Resources.SelectMany(r => r.Teams, (r,t) => new { r, t })
         .Where(x => x.t.Id == 1)
         .Select(x => x.r)
```

---

NOTE: If you will not try to translate query syntax into method syntax, but just focus on same result, then you can also use following query (well, results will be slightly different if there is duplications in resource teams - you will not get duplicated resouces with this query)

```
Resources.Where(r => r.Teams.Any(t => t.Id == 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Resources
    .SelectMany(x => x.Teams, (resource, team) => new { Resource = resource, Team = team })
    .Where(x => x.Team.Id == 1)
    .Select(x => x.Resource);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query works:

```
Teams.Where(t => t.Id == 1).SelectMany(r => r.Resources)
```

Comment: Yes, but it's not the same :) You changed order of operations

Comment: Ultimately what I am trying to get at is the Resources that have the team Id 1 in their collection of teams.